# Output column name from an array and compute average of an array

Tags: php, sql

I have this as my function to sort out multiple values (average in my case) and I can already output the highest *value(average)*. What I want to do now is instead of outputting the highest *value(average)* is to output the column name that contains the highest *value(average)*. I have tried `mysql_fetch_field()` but it outputs `null` for me. Also, is there a way to compute for the `average($averagesa)` ?

```
<?php

    usort($averagesa, function($a, $b) {  // $averagesa contains several averages
    if ($a['avg'] == $b['avg']) {         // from multiple queries
           return 0;
    }

    return ($a['avg'] > $b['avg']) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $highesta = $averagesa[0];   
    echo $highesta['avg'];               // highest average value

?>
```

this is the sample query, i want to output the columns (i.e C1.1) if it contains the highest average

```
  <html>
<table>
<tr><th>Campus</th>
<th>No. of Staff</th>
<th>C1.1</th>
<th>C1.2</th>
<th>C1.3</th>
<th>C1.4</th>
<th>C1.5</th>
<th>C1.6</th>
<th>C2.1</th>
<th>C2.2</th>
<th>C2.3</th>
<th>C3.1</th>
<th>C3.2</th>
<th>C3.3</th>
<th>C3.4</th>
<th>AVERAGE</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>MAIN 1 - CABEIHM</td>
<?php

    $querya1 = ("SELECT ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2), dept_code, camp_code
                 FROM performance 
                 INNER JOIN employment 
                 ON employment.emp_code=performance.emp_id 
                 AND employment.dept_code=performance.dept_id
                 WHERE empg_code=1  AND dept_id=3");

    $resulta1 = mysql_query($querya1) or die(mysql_error());

    // Print out result
    while($rowa1 = mysql_fetch_array($resulta1))
    {
        $averagesa[1] = array(
            'avg' => $rowa1['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'],
            'empg_code' => 1,
            'dept_id' => 3,
            'dept_code' => $rowa1['dept_code'],
            'camp_code' => $rowa1['camp_code']
        );
        echo "".$rowa1['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: Need to show a sample of the array and what column you want to return.

Comment: 1. Can you provide some of the original data you're working with? All we see is a variable called $averagesa, but is there an $averagesb, or does averagesa contain all of the averages...? 

2. In case you haven't already considered it, you might want to try to use the built-in MySQL functions for calculating things like average, max, min, etc...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I added the sample of the codes.

Comment: about the built in functions, i have tried but it outputs null for me, i don't know if im doing it wrong or what.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pure SQL solution that outputs the *dept_code* and *camp_code*  corresponding to highest average. Assign this one-row value to your PHP array. Also, a `GROUP BY` clause is added to the query for correct ANSI-compliant  aggregation.

```sql
SELECT t.dept_code, t.camp_code, t.avg_comp
FROM
  (SELECT ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2) as avg_comp, dept_code, camp_code
   FROM performance 
   INNER JOIN employment 
   ON employment.emp_code=performance.emp_id 
   AND employment.dept_code=performance.dept_id
   WHERE empg_code=1  AND dept_id=3
   GROUP BY dept_code, camp_code) as t
ORDER BY t.avg_comp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That could work, but the avg_comp is not actually saved in our table, it is just a result from our query. Did I understand your code correctly or am I wrong?

Comment: *avg_comp* is being calculated here. This query borrows exactly from your original SQL with added `GROUP BY` and an outer query for the highest average.